# Restricting generic type to an enumeration type

Tags: scala, generics, enums, typeclass

Say I want to define some generic type and have the guarantee that it will only be instantiated when the generic parameter is one of a known list of types. One way to do that, using typeclasses, is

```
sealed trait Allowed[A]
object Allowed {
  implicit object string extends Allowed[String]
  implicit object int extends Allowed[Int]
}
case class Player[A: Allowed](id: A, name: String, score: Double)
```

In this case, I know that `Player` can have an id that is a `String` or an `Int`, but nothing else. I can leverage that information in functions such as the following

```
def retrievePlayerById[A: Allowed](p: Player[A]) =
  implicitly[Allowed[A]] match {
    case Allowed.string =>
      val id = p.id.asInstanceOf[String]
      ...
    case Allowed.int =>
      val id = p.id.asInstanceOf[Int]
      ...
  }
```

Now, my problem is the following. I would like to do the same, but allowing the generic parameter to be either a `String`, or any enumeration type.

I do not care much if enumerations are to be encoded like this:

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
  type WeekDay = Value
  val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
}
```

or like this

```
trait WeekDay
case object Mon extends WeekDay
case object Tue extends WeekDay
case object Wed extends WeekDay
case object Thu extends WeekDay
case object Fri extends WeekDay
case object Sat extends WeekDay
case object Sun extends WeekDay
```

although the former would be a little more convenient for other reasons.

Any ideas how to do that?

**EDIT:** A first attempt goes like this

```
sealed trait Allowed[A]
object Allowed {
  implicit object string extends Allowed[String]
  implicit def enum[A <: Enumeration] = new Allowed[A#Value] {}
}
```

This works in restricting the type, now the problem is pattern matching on it. I can do

```
def foo[A: Allowed] = implicitly[Allowed[A]] match {
  case Allowed.string =>
    // everything ok in this branch
  case _ =>
    // here I don't know how to persuade the compiler that A is
    // an enumeration type
}
```

In order to convince the compiler that I have an enumeration type, I have also tried matching with

```
case n: Allowed[(A forSome { type A <: Enumeration })#Value] =>
```

or similarly

```
case n: Allowed[A#Value forSome { type A <: Enumeration }] =>
```

but both are rejected by the compiler saying that `Value` is not a type member of `A` (even though I constrain `A` to extend `Enumeration`)